# Register file in Verilog, How to make it so reads only happen on negedge

Tags: fpga, verilog, register, quartus

So this is my current code.

```
  module top
  (input clk,
   input reset,
   input write,
   input [4:0] wrAddr,
   input [31:0] wrData,
   input [4:0] rdAddrA,
   output [31:0] rdDataA,
   input [4:0] rdAddrB,
   output [31:0] rdDataB);

   reg [31:0]    regfile [0:31];

   assign rdDataA = regfile[rdAddrA];
   assign rdDataB = regfile[rdAddrB];

   integer   i;

   always @(posedge clk) begin
      if (reset) begin
            for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1) begin
                regfile[i] <= 0;
            end
      end else begin
            if (write) regfile[wrAddr] <= wrData;
      end // else: !if(reset)
   end

    endmodule
```

It works fine, but it reads immediately.  I want to set this up so it reads only on the falling edge of the clock cycle.  I'm not sure how to add posedge and negedge blocks without running into issues with constant drivers.  Any tips on the proper way to do this would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Reading from a register is inherently asynchronous. I think what you really want is for `rdDataA` and `rdDataB` to be updated only at a falling clock edge. To accomplish this, just put their assignments inside an `always @(negedge clk)` block and use non-blocking assignments instead of the concurrent `assign` statement.

```
always @(negedge clk) begin
    rdDataA <= regfile[rdAddrA];
    rdDataB <= regfile[rdAddrB];
end
```

Comment: Don't forget to change `output [31:0]` to `output reg [31:0]` otherwise it would be considered net types which cannot be assigned in an always block.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly.